# Javascript replacing text in string with other text

Tags: javascript, regex, search, replace

I am creating a linking system that needs to be cross platform, i.e work on a webapp as well as a mobile app.

The API returns a string that looks like this,

`Go to {P}Project Name{/P}`

OR

`Go to {F}File Name{/F}`

I need to search for an occurance of {P} and {F} and replace this with a `<a href="">` on my webapp, and then search for {/P} or {/F} and replace that with `</a>`

I am trying to do this with javascript but I am coming unstuck, here is what I have so far,

```
var body = this.get('body');
if(body.match( \({P}|{F}/) {

}
```

after this I come unstuck my regex knowledge is not what it should be, can some point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Multiple replacement can be done with a global regex: `body = body.replace(/\{[PF]}/g, '<a href="">').replace(/\{\/[PF]}/g, '</a>')`.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
str = str.replace(/({[PF]}(.*?){\/[PF]})/g, '<a href="">$2</a>');
```

For `Go to <a href="">Project Name</a>`

Comment: It fails when the string looks like `Go to {P}Project Name{/P} as well as to {F}Project File{/F}`

Comment: It would ouput `Go to <a href="">Project Name</a>`

Comment: Indeed, my bad, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
str = "Go to {P}Project Name{/P}"
str = str.replace(/({P}|{F})/, '<a href="">');
str = str.replace(/({\/P}|{\/F})/, '</a>');
alert(str);
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/jygmpesx/)

---

Shorter updated solution:

```
str = "Go to {P}Project Name{/P}"
str = str.replace(/({P}|{F})(.*?)({\/P}|{\/F})/g, '<a href="">$2</a>');
alert(str);
```

[**See Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jygmpesx/2/)

Comment: Proabbly wan ta `g` flag on that, there's no need for the capture group, and you need to escape the `{` and `}`. *Edit:* Huh, it seems to figure out that the `{` and `}` are literals, presumably because they don't have a number inside them. Still...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder demo is giving expected output. Is there need to escape `{`. I don't think.

Comment: `{` and `}` have special meaning, they're quantifiers. But apparently, if you have something inside them that isn't a digit, the engine figures it out. Still, I would escape them.

Comment: Great advice added updated solution with escaping `{` & `}`. Thanks @T.J.Crowder.

Comment: the second demo fails with `str = "Go to {P}Project Name{/P} as well as to {F}name{/F}"`

Comment: The `}` does not have to be escaped as it is unambiguous in all contexts.

Comment: Still fails @Alex K. has the best solution so far ;)

Comment: Updated solution. Test it once.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the JS regex tuturials either at [Javascript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml) or at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

In your case, you're failing to open the regex with a slash (`/`), and there's also the fact that brackets (`{}`) have a special significance on a regular expression, so you'll have to escape it.

Your regex should be something like `/\{[PF]\}(.*?)\{\/[PF]\}/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf (pure JS) to check whether you can find {P} or {F} in your string. Then replace them.

```
var str = "Go to {P}Project Name{/P}"; //this is just an example, it may contains F
if (str.indexOf("{P}" != -1} {//will return -1 if it doesn't have
    str = str.replace("{P}", "<a href="">");
    str = str.replace("{/P}", "</a>");
} else {
    str = str.replace("{F}", "<a href="">");
    str = str.replace("{/F}", "</a>");
}
```